# How do I quantify an adhesive's ability to stick in contrast to flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, adhesion, rheology

Let's say you glue a ball to a shovel.

How do you quantify this adhesive's and ball's ability to stick to the shovel, moving at different speeds, in air and then while the shovel digs into the ground?

This suggests an adhesive could work so "well" that it effectively becomes added mass to the shovel. For some adhesives like superglue, you could adhere a small enough mass to resist...an anti-velocity vector? Anti-force vector? Anti-acceleration vector? or a certain critical mass? Eventually, there's some "breaking point" for the adhesive where the stickiness stops being the case and the adhesive would unstick after being sheared from the shovel as it digs into the ground.

I've never studied adhesive and fluid mechanics formally. How do you quantify any of this? An adhesive is resisting...what in the air and in the ground? Acceleration? Force? Momentum? Googling doesn't give me a lot of great results.

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but I think rheology might be relevant here.

Comment: The glue and the ball **are** added mass.  If the glue has elasticity, there'll be some sort of lag between accelerating the shovel and the ball accelerating in response.    And, yes, you will want to know the elasticity limit, the shear strength of the glue in the configuration of interest, etc.